# add days onto string date swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I have a variety of dates in String format, held in a dictionary. I would like to retrieve these dates and add one or two days onto them, depending on other criteria.

Do I need to convert the string dates to NSDate, extract the components (year, month, day), edit the components (adding one or two days) and put the new components back together again in NSDate/String?

For example, I have a string date from my dictionary "26/05/2018" and I want to add one day on, I want to produce a new string "27/05/2018".

Thanks

Comment: As a general recommendation - yes

Comment: You should not have any strings for your date. Convert them all to `Date` as soon as possible. The only time you should convert one to a String is to display it to the user.

Comment: Why the requirement to store a string in the dictionary? Why not store a date and format it as need for display?

Comment: And no, you do not need to deal with splitting the date back forth into components. Use the `date(byAdding:value:to:wrappingComponents:)` to increment the date.

Answer (score 1):

1. Convert String to Date using appropriate DateFormatter
2. Add components to get new Date
3. Return the date

Answer (score 0):

You could start with something like this:

```
extension String {

    func toDate(format: String) -> Date? {

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
        return dateFormatter.date(from: self)
    }
}

extension Date {

    func toString(format: String) -> String? {

        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = format
        return df.string(from: self)
    }

    func add(component: Calendar.Component, value: Int) -> Date? {

        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: component, value: value, to: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why hardcode a Gregorian calendar in the code? Just use `Calendar.current`.